# How fill matrix with loop for and same value for colum

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have this matrix:

```
mat_A <- matrix(ncol=7,nrow=12)
```

I would fill the columns of  `mat_A` with same values for each column, in a range of values from 5 to 11. The expected result is:

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
 [1,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
 [2,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
 [3,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
 [4,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
 [5,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
 [6,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
 [7,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
 [8,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
 [9,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
[10,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
[11,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
[12,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
```

I know that i can tray colum by column, like :

```
mat_A[,1] <- 5
....
mat_A[,7] <- 11
```

But why i can do this with loop `for?`
I tried with:

```
pippo <- rep(5:11,each=12)
  for(j in 1:ncol(mat_A)){
    mat_A[j,] <- pippo
  }
```

but the error is:

```
Error in mat_A[j, ] <- pippo : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Any idea?

Comment: How long is this `rep(5:11,each=12)`? How long is this `mat_A[j,]`? That's why your code fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a loop. Try

```
mat_A <- matrix(ncol=7,nrow=12)
mat_A <- col(mat_A)+4
mat_A
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
# [2,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
# [3,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
# [4,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
# [5,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
# [6,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
# [7,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
# [8,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
# [9,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
#[10,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
#[11,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
#[12,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to use the loop as described in the OP, the code can be used after two modifications:

1. remove `each=12`, and
2. loop over the rows, not the columns.

Therefore, this works, too:

```
pippo <- rep(5:11)
for(j in 1:nrow(mat_A)){
    mat_A[j,] <- pippo
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply construct the matrix:

```
mat_A <- matrix(rep(5:11, each=12), 12)
```

Here the results of microbenchmark for the three answers:

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(
+   by.row= matrix(5:11,ncol=7,nrow=12,byrow=TRUE), 
+   rep=matrix(rep(5:11, each=12), 12),
+   col.plus=col(matrix(ncol=7,nrow=12))+4,
+   loop={mat_A <- matrix(ncol=7,nrow=12); pippo <- rep(5:11);    for(j in 1:nrow(mat_A))     mat_A[j,] <- pippo }
+ )
Unit: microseconds
     expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval cld
   by.row  2.681  2.9505  3.27668  3.0955  3.3025 14.087   100 a  
      rep  3.780  4.0580  4.26584  4.2170  4.3485  5.707   100 ab 
 col.plus  4.230  4.5000  4.81078  4.6905  4.8680 10.853   100  b 
     loop 17.946 18.4055 19.87737 18.6970 19.1745 65.719   100   c
```

Answer (score 1):

The `matrix` function has a `byrow` argument which can be used with R's recycling behavior for this purpose

```
matrix(5:11,ncol=7,nrow=12,byrow=TRUE)
```